# Unable to pass parameter from command to converter

Tags: plugins, ecmascript-6, ckeditor, textcolor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to edit the actual existing plugin of highlight to be able to add text color customizable from command argument, which means that if you put RGB or hex color it will take it on the selection create a  view attribute style = 'color: PARAMETER'

What I got so far just surround the text with font tag and the style attribute with color but with a color value incorrect.

Which mean the value on the command is not being passed to the converter.

I'm being unable to find a way to transfer input information from a command to use directly in the converter to make this feature works.

The normal behavior in this plugin make it impossible to use the 16 million colors from RGB, and it requires an obsolete model of defined colors.

You can see/edit/use what i've done so far in this repo

https://github.com/klys/ckeditor5-highlight-inline

In this part the converter create the font element with the style color but with a incorrect value for color value.

```
editor.conversion.attributeToElement( {
        model: HIGHLIGHT,
            view: {
                name: 'font',
                styles: {
                    'color': true
                },
                priority: 5,
                model: {
                    key: 'highlight',
                    value: viewElement => viewElement.getAttribute( 'color' )
                },
                type:'pen'
            }
    } );
```

And this the edited command executor from the original plugin, which i edit to meet the needs of this feature.

```
    execute( color ) {

    const model = this.editor.model;
    const document = model.document;
    const selection = document.selection;

    //const highlighter = options.value;
    /*var __model;
    for ( const option of options ) {
     __model = new Model( {
            model: 'color model',
            class: 'color-class',
            title: 'color pen',
            color: option.value,
            type: 'pen'
        } );
    }
    const highlighter = __model;*/

    model.change( writer => {
        const ranges = model.schema.getValidRanges( selection.getRanges(), 'highlight' );

        if ( selection.isCollapsed ) {
            const position = selection.getFirstPosition();

            // When selection is inside text with `highlight` attribute.
            if ( selection.hasAttribute( 'highlight' ) ) {
                // Find the full highlighted range.
                const isSameHighlight = value => {
                    return value.item.hasAttribute( 'highlight' ) && value.item.getAttribute( 'highlight' ) === this.value;
                };

                const highlightStart = position.getLastMatchingPosition( isSameHighlight, { direction: 'backward' } );
                const highlightEnd = position.getLastMatchingPosition( isSameHighlight );
                const highlightRange = writer.createRange( highlightStart, highlightEnd );

                // Then depending on current value...
                if ( !color || this.value === color ) {
                    // ...remove attribute when passing highlighter different then current or executing "eraser".
                    writer.removeAttribute( 'highlight', highlightRange );
                    writer.removeSelectionAttribute( 'highlight' );
                } else {
                    // ...update `highlight` value.
                    writer.setAttribute( 'highlight', color, highlightRange );
                    writer.setSelectionAttribute( 'highlight', color );
                }
            } else if ( color ) {
                writer.setSelectionAttribute( 'highlight', color );
            }
        } else {
            for ( const range of ranges ) {
                if ( color ) {
                    writer.setAttribute( 'highlight', color, range );
                } else {
                    writer.removeAttribute( 'highlight', range );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
}
```

I have been almost a week in this problem.

If you can a least point me out in the right direction, you won't imagine how much you will help me.